# how to get search value from data base using php if 2 or 3 words same to stored data base value

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

my code is fine and its working well but i have to write same term as its stored in data base 
like if i want to search a value named"awais123" which is stored in data base i have to write same term as "awais123"
if i will write awa or aws it will return nothing

//my **datauser.php**

```
<form action="data2.php" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="Search" name="user_name" value="" placeholder="Search..."    class="form-control" />
     <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-info">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       </button>
     </div>
  < /div>
</form>
```

//now my **"data2.php"**

```
 <?php 
            include("db/opendb.php"); 
            $username=$_POST['user_name'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name='".$username."'";
   $result = $conn ->query($query) or die("Query error");
 ?>
  <table width="983" border="1" cellpadding="5" class="insertTable">
  <tr>

    <td width="109"><strong>user name</strong></td>

    <td width="38"><strong>user phone no</strong></td>
    <td width="99"><strong>dept id</strong></td>
    <td width="40"><strong></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
  ?>

  <tr>

     <td><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></td>

      <td><?php echo $row['user_phone_no']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['dept_id']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>">Delete</a>        </td>
  </tr>
     <?php
     }
        ?>
```

please help me i just want that if just 3 words are found in my term its      display result

Comment: have you looked at the SQL SELECT LIKE statement? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: yes i used it but its not working

Comment: 3 words or 3 letters? You are open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you $query to:-

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name LIKE '%".$username."'%";
```